# How does WordPress redirect without using .htaccess?

Tags: redirect

As explained [here](https://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/turn-off-wordpress-homepage-url-redirection/), WordPress has Automatic URL Redirects. However, it's **not** based on .htaccess which WordPress keeps [to a minimum](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/why-you-cant-find-htaccess-file-on-your-wordpress-site/).

Let's say your "siteurl" setting (in the GUI) contains "www.". If a visitor didn't use "www", how and in which file does WordPress manage to detect that and redirect accordingly?

Comment: It would seem the class is setup and some work within /wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php. I'm looking into it further and learning new stuff - that's always good.

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is that wordpress uses wp_redirect() to perform redirects. You can see the source here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

The implied part of your question -- about how wordpress decides when to do so -- is a bit more complicated and might be influenced by plugins such as yoast. But, for example, if wordpress's rewrite rules select a post which has a different canonical url from the requested url, wordpress may redirect to the canonical url.